# Which displays can be operated with the Compute Module IO Board V3?

Tags: compute-module, dsi, compute-module-3

Are there displays that were developed to work with the DSI ports of the Compute Module IO Board V3? I am looking for color displays as well e-ink displays.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Compute Module's documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/RPI-CM-DATASHEET-V1_0.pdf):

> Currently the DSI interface is not openly documented and only DSI
>   displays supported by the official Raspberry Pi firmware will work
>   with this interface.

I'd suggest taking a look at the [official Raspberry Pi display](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/the-eagerly-awaited-raspberry-pi-display/), which should, I think, be supported.